# Finding the weeks of each year separately in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

all. Could you please help me print the week of each year separately? I try to find the week of years by  the help of `visit['week_start']=visit['start_ts'].dt.week`  code . But it mixes of all years and prints as one the same week. For example, `2017.01.01` and `2018.01.01` are 0 weak. But I want to print them separately such as `2017 0` weeks and `2018 0` weeks.  Thanks in advance.

start_ts is here

[image]

week_start is here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['week_start'] = df.start_ts.dt.isocalendar()['year'].astype(str) + \
                   ' ' + df.start_ts.dt.isocalendar()['week'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you a lot for your help . I get the error: DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'isocalendar . and I cannot find why this error occur .

Comment: Using `isocalendar()` as an accessor has been introduced in pandas 1.1 if I recall correctly. Which pandas version do you get from `pd.__version__`?

Comment: Does it work if you try `df['week_start'] = df.start_ts.isocalendar()[0].astype(str) + ' ' + df.start_ts.isocalendar()[1].astype(str)`?

Answer (score 0):

accumulate the years in a list then use the date_range for each year to find the weeks in that year and use as a mask

```
index= pd.date_range(start='2021-1-1',periods=52,freq='W')
print(index)
```